# Reversing order of integers in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

I have this problem below. I am trying to complete a program that reads multiple input from the user to form an array, then outputs the array in reverse order.

First line of input n should be the number of integers in the array. The next input should be the values of each index in the array.

My first time working with arrays in C++ and found this confusing, I've searched and found there's a way to do this in a single line, but I would like to complete this without it. I tried if statements and for loops over the current loop there, but each time I would end up over complicating it and would get nowhere.  I'm sure there's a simple way i'm missing.

Example input -

4

1 2 3 4

Output should be -

4 3 2 1

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;


int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    for(int arr_i = 0;arr_i < n;arr_i++){
       int* arr = new int[n];
       cin >> arr[arr_i];      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of includes. You can get by with `vector` and `iostream`. Improve readability and give the compiler a lot less work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::reverse()` function from `<algorithm>` like described in this documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

```
std::reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

If you don't need to reverse your vector, but just print in reverse order, you can also backwardly iterate on it:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it = arr.rbegin(); it != arr.rend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << " ";
```

**Warning:** be careful about your line `int* arr = new int[n];`, it's seems to be a memory leak. This is hiding the real symbol of your array `arr`, and then your local variable `arr` is then lost. You should just remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the smallest edit you can make to your current code to make it work. Note you don't need to allocate a new `arr` in the for loop body as you already have a vector with that name.

```
int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> arr(n);
    for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++){
       cin >> arr[n-arr_i-1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```